# Unwanted background showing in html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to integrate 4 images together. But unfortunately the images are padding a few pixels in the bottom.

You can see the problem here:

[image]

I just want to close all the images without any border or any padding.

**CSS:**

```
    #play {   
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .ui-grid-b img {
       width  : 100%;
       height : auto;
        }


    #play ul {
        border: 0px solid black;       
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 50%;
        height: 450px;
        float: left;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #play ul li {
        background-image: none;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

     #play ul li.list1 {
        background-color: #ff0000;

    }
    #play ul li.list2 {
        background-color: #00ff00;

    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="play" class="ui-grid-b">
    <ul id="list1">
        <li class="list1">
            <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="Smiley face">
        </li>
        <li class="list1">
            <img src="images/img3.jpg" alt="Smiley face">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="list2">
        <li class="list2">
            <img src="images/img2.jpg" alt="Smiley face">
        </li>
        <li class="list2">
            <img src="images/img4.jpg" alt="Smiley face">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `font-size: 0;` to your `#play ul li`' css attributes:

```
   #play ul li {
        background-image: none;
        list-style-type: none;
        font-size: 0;  /* <-- the magic */  
    }
```

Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/HhVQ5/1/

Answer (score 0):

li as I understand has it's own default padding and margin too. Trying removing them by using

```
 #play ul li {
    background-image: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

}
```